# WebRTC - WebRTC: ICE failed, add a STUN server and see about:webrtc for more details

Tags: video-streaming, webrtc, ssh-tunnel, stun

I am trying to stream a video to a browser using WebRTC. The error I am receiving is `WebRTC: ICE failed, add a STUN server and see about:webrtc for more details`.
This is a bit surprising to me because in my code I am mentioning one of googles STUN servers in the config-object for the peer connection like this:

```
const config = {
        iceServers: [
          {
            urls: ['stun:stun.l.google.com:19302']
          }
        ]
      };
```

I already tested this on the PC, the project is running on and was able to see the stream there.
Now I wanted to access the website over an ssh tunnel. I forwarded the port and can now open localhost:4000 in the browser and see the website however the video won't show up and I'll get the described error.

How can I stream the video also to the remote PC or why is it not working over the ssh tunnel?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem? I'm running into something similar. Can't get it to work via an ssh tunnel. Turned off all my fireware and everything.

Comment: Unfortunately not, I had to switch my attention to another project. However I am also still interested in solving this issue and will add updates here, if I find have any news. Have you found any piece of information that sounded promising?

Comment: I ended up running all the Janus servers on one machine with WSL2 and then I SSH'd into WSL2 with my Mac and forwarded one of the front end ports. It's a total mess, especially when WSL2 changes ports on every restart. It makes no sense because that's the same thing I was doing when I was running those servers in the cloud.